# Compass PATH Needs Correcting

Tags: ruby, terminal, yeoman, compass

I'm trying to play around with Yeoman and I'm trying to use Compass in my scaffold, but the Terminal keeps on throwing up this error when I run `grunt`.

```
Warning: Couldn't find the `compass` binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH Use --force to continue.
```

I think this may have something to do with the way I have Compass installed. I might have installed two copies, one via RVM and another via another method.

Does anyone know how to fix this error. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04 having both the apt-get and the rvm versions installed. I uninstalled the ubuntu package:

```
sudo apt-get uninstall ruby-compass
```

Then I re-installed the RVM version following some instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/stephou0104/233b5c99884f1d8c8b8b) and [here](https://kalamuna.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23134210).
Basically:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm requirements
rvm install ruby
rvm use ruby --default
rvm rubygems current
gem install sass
gem install compass
```

Then I did a restart and it worked.